# xp_cmdshell throwing 'null' but working in command prompt

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, xp-cmdshell

I am using `xp_cmdshell` command to process csv file to a folder. My query is as below:

```
Exec master..xp_cmdshell 'C:\test\mydotnetapp.exe -s:03/09/2020 -t:1 -l:1,2,3,4,7 -d C:\test'
```

In SSMS this command returns null. But in command prompt when I do:

```
cd C:\test
mydotnetapp.exe -s:03/09/2020 -t:1 -l:1,2,3,4,7 -d C:\test
```

The same query is working perfectly fine. A couple of things:

1. xp_cmdshell is enabled
2. SQL Server has access to the folder
3. Only this `xp_cmdshell` command is not working. my other `xp_cmdshell` is working fine

Any help on how this can be fixed?

Comment: "my other xp_cmdshell is working fine" means nothing to anyone else. Does it use that application? Notice in your "working version" you change the currrent directory before starting the app. What does "throwing null" mean? Does your app catch and log errors? If not - it should because how else will you debug your code when run in a non-interactive fashion?

Answer (score 0):

If this is run as part of a SQL Job regularly scheduled, run it as a task outside of SQL Server.

Many production DBAs won't let any process run XP_CMDSHELL given the security issues.

If the CSV is well-formed, it can be mapped into SQL Server as a table (not recommended).

It can be imported directly into SQL Server.

Lastly, many production DBAs won't install any custom process code on a production SQL Server machine.  The SQL Server machine is dedicated to running only SQL Server plus the minimum extra needed for security and monitoring.